# Extraction of error spectrum in Sloan Digital Sky Survey

Tags: spectroscopy, spectra, quasars

I need to know does SDSS spectrum contains error spectrum as well?

http://www.sdss.org/dr12/spectro/spectro_basics/#AbouttheSpectra

The above link says, further HDU's contain error spectrum and than tells about the inverse variance. Does inverse variance contains error spectrum? If yes, how can I extract that, if not where can I find error spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance is the square of the standard deviation, so you can calculate 1$\sigma$ errors of the spectrum by taking the square root of one over the inverse variance of HDU1 (https://data.sdss.org/datamodel/files/SPECTRO_REDUX/RUN2D/PLATE4/spPlate.html#hdu1head).

(You will get infinity for bad pixels since their inverse variance is set to zero.)

Comment: Is there anyway to increase the level of sigma error?

Comment: Absolutely right. The inverse variance is used because that is directly what you use to weight any fit to a model.

Comment: @syedali, like the 3sigma error? typically you assume a normal distribution and just multiply  1sigma  by 3 (for example). see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_tolerance_intervals